# Screenshot of a webpage using Edge

Tags: screenshot, microsoft-edge, webpage

I want to take a screenshot of a webpage from the command line. I have managed to achieve this in Chrome and Firefox using the following command:

`"c:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --headless --screenshot="C:\tmp\screen.png" --window-size=1280,720 "https://bbc.co.uk/news"`

I'm trying to do the same using Microsoft Edge but can't seem to find any info. My thinking is that 99% of Windows machines will have this preinstalled and in the same location.

Comment: Have you tried these command line options with the latest version of Edge?

Comment: Yes. Trying to run against the Edge exe has no effect. Even trying to just run the Edge exe with no arguments from the command line has no effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a guess, but Edge may simply not implement these features (at least not yet).

Edge based on Chromium has existed for just about a year (as of this writing) but the "official" build wasn't even released until January 2020. And this [Microsoft Tech Community](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/enterprise/taking-full-page-screenshot/m-p/1109589#) post seems to indicate built-in screenshots weren't available then, either.

Answer (score 4):

The latest Edge Chromium versions work pretty well to snapshot a page, even on an older server OS, such as Windows 2012R2:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Edge\Application\msedge.exe" --headless --disable-gpu --window-size=1280,720 --screenshot="C:\tmp\screen.png" "https://bbc.co.uk/news"
```

Similarly, you can also create a PDF from a web page by changing the screenshot argument:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Edge\Application\msedge.exe" --headless --disable-gpu --window-size=1280,720 --print-to-pdf-no-header --print-to-pdf="C:\tmp\screen.pdf" "https://bbc.co.uk/news"
```

Comment: Any reason for the downvote? I'm performing this successfully in production with 10,000 customers, and I'd like to know if this technique has a particular issue.

Comment: (Not the downvoter) Have you had issues with the process not closing when you're done running this command? Chrome closes itself when it's done, but Edge appears to be sticking around.

Comment: @seadoggie01 I just checked our primary app servers, one has it loaded, one does not. But it doesn't seem to be hurting anything. Perhaps it closes after a period of time. I know it can stay open if you have service workers, but I don't think we have any of those configured.